# Update table columns based on values in other table

Tags: mysql, sql, apache-spark-sql

I have two tables

```
                 showroom
============================================
model_id    car_name         is_available
--------------------------------------------
   0        rav4              false
   1        tacoma            false
   2        corolla           false
   3        tundra            false
```

and

```
      warehouse
========================
model_id    car_name         
------------------------
   0        rav4              
   1        tacoma
```

The primary key is `model_id`. I want to update the column `showroom.is_available` to true if the `model_id` is present in `warehouse`. So the output according to the above example would be

```
                  showroom
    ============================================
    model_id    car_name         is_available
    --------------------------------------------
       0        rav4              true
       1        tacoma            true
       2        corolla           false
       3        tundra            false
```

I know I can do

```
UPDATE showroom
SET is_available = true
WHERE model_id IN (
SELECT model_id
FROM warehouse
);
```

But both tables have over a billion rows, and even though I am using Spark SQL the queries are very slow

Comment: what is your rdbms?

Comment: @BryanDellinger These are delta tables on databricks. I am using spark sql

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  a.model_id
  ,a.car_name
  ,CASE WHEN b.model_id IS NOT NULL THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END is_available
FROM
  showroom a
  LEFT OUTER JOIN warehouse b ON (a.model_id = b.model_id)
```

Comment: Why should the OP ___try this___? **Good answers** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way,
not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO that may find this question and be reading your answer. If it is well answered maybe they will UpVote it.

Answer (score 0):

On big tables a join is faster than the IN clause

And see if you can#t reduce the number

For showroom you can use a combined index on (model_id,is_available)

When you are able also reduce the number of possible candidates

```
UPDATE showroom s
INNER JOIN warehouse w ON s.model_id = w.model_id
SET s.is_available = true
WHERE s.is_available = FALSE
```

Comment: What CV h mysql versions are you using ?

Comment: you should use merge https://docs.delta.io/0.4.0/delta-update.html